# Eclipse ADT : R resolution

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have installed Eclipse and attached/installed ADT to it.
In my case:
Eclipse, Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Android Development Toolkit, Version: 23.0.6.1720515

I'm getting an error "R cannot be resolved to a variable". "R.java" is present in the "gen" folder of the project. How do I correct this.

Comment: Try to clean the project

Comment: It's recommended to use `Android Studio` now, but yeah cleaning and rebuilding should fix that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)